# Jquery ":empty" not working - To check if all <DIV> contains some text or empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I generated few boxes at runtime, where I want to confirm if all the boxes is "Empty", then the user should not be able to proceed. But if **even a single Box** contains the correct value (instead of Empty), then user should be able to proceed.

I created the below code:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    setProceedState();

});

function setProceedState() {
    if ($('.type').length == $('.type:empty').length) {
        alert("Empty" + $(".type").html());
        $("#stepAutomapConfirm").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#stepAutomapConfirm").addClass("disabled").removeClass("active");
    } else {
        alert("NOT Empty" + $(".type").html());
        $("#stepAutomapConfirm").attr("disabled", false);
        $("#stepAutomapConfirm").addClass("active").removeClass("disabled");
    }
}
```

Somehow this code is working fine in the fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/xJtAV/**

But on my **MVC Partial View** page its not fully working:

It always give me the correct alert if the boxes are "empty",

**BUT** when it generates boxes with data in it **at runtime**, **it still shows "EMPTY" alert.** I checked the "view source" and "inspect element" too, in source the data do exist, and then, when I manually refresh my page after that it gives the correct alerts "**NOT Empty**".

Please suggest what I am missing or what can be the alternative for **JQuery** "`:empty`" to make the code work in **MVC Partial View**!

Let me know if you need any other information!

Comment: .type seems like a class that could possibly be used by some other elements elsewhere, you sure nothing else is using that class that could be skewing your results?

Comment: ".type" is the class in the boxes in which I get the Values, if you refer the fiddle, that might give a better idea...

Comment: I understand that, but your fiddle works just fine, the problem is with your real site, which obviously has more elements than that fiddle. does THAT site have additional elements on the page with that class. with what you've given us so far, all we can do is guess because you haven't replicated your problem. you've shown us that your code works on it's own, therefore the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: No, only inside the boxes I have the ".type" class. The strange this is, not just in Fiddle this code also working fine on my page when the ".type" <div> is blank, it just dont refresh or check automatically when the data has been added... and when I manually refresh then it detects that <div class="type>" has some value inside.

Comment: if statements don't automagically rerun when it's condition changes...

Comment: so what can I change to make it working?

Comment: run said function in the success callback of whatever is changing the divs.

Comment: Superb, it worked, initially I added my "IF" function on ".ready" and on ".click" of the button which generates the boxes, but now I just added the function after the success of "generating the boxes" too and it started working as expected... Thanks a ton, Please add as answer so I can select!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-execute your function after you generate the boxes, on ready only works for boxes that exist at dom ready.